# How to set Referrer Policy with nginx

Tags: nginx, referrer, referrer-policy

My CMS(https) and image server(http) is separate. I have setup my image server so that it only can serve to whitelisted referrer pages. Now my issue is how do I allow the CMS server to send response header to the image server so the CMS can display the images? I have found giving this html meta tag in the html will display the images.

```
<meta name="referrer" content="origin">
```

but is it possible to　do this without editing each html page and do this server side? I am on Nginx v1.10.2

Answer (score 37):

Simply adding below solved my issue.

```
add_header 'Referrer-Policy' 'origin';
```

Answer (score 6):

You actually dont need quotes on Refferer-Policy if you add the line into default.conf.

```
add_header Referrer-Policy 'origin'
```

Here you can also see other values https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy

Comment: you do however need to end with a semicolon: `add_header Referrer-Policy 'strict-origin';`

Comment: That would of landed the correct wave of upvotes. I trust this over all. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
    location / {
        add_header 'Referrer-Policy' 'unsafe-url';
    }
```

Comment: Could you name the (dis-)advantageous of your solutions compared to the existing answers, please? Any additional explanation could be valuable, I guess.