# How to prevent direct link access to files in a specific folder using nginx?

Tags: nginx, hyperlink, block

how to block direct link?

I have files subtitles want to block direct link and access.
But this referrer block access to my domain too

```
location ~\.(vtt|srt|txt)$ {
    allow localhost;
    deny all;
    return 404;
}

location ~ \.vtt {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.vtt)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: So you would like access to be granted when the referrer is one of your own pages, and denied otherwise?

Comment: Possibly related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43447490/how-to-set-referrer-policy-with-nginx

Comment: @joanis yes, but when I server block directory images, still can display

but not for files subtitle .vtt